# Crawlera HTTPS pages permanently timing out

Tags: https, web-scraping, scrapy, timeout, web-crawler

I'm using crawlera with scrapy to crawl a https website. crawlera works fine with http websites, but when it comes to https it's timing out constantly. I followed their guide to import the crawlera certificate but it was no use, I'm still getting the timeout problem even with the sample test included in their website https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000188407-crawlera-with-https. Im using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Scrapy does not check server certificates, so scrapy should work fine with Crawlera without additional CA certificate [(source)](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-crawlera/issues/28). Can you paste the error you are getting ?

Comment: 2018-09-11 18:52:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.canlii.org/en/> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.canlii.org/en/ took longer than 190 seconds..

Comment: This is not the error, this is a retry, can you paste the log when the request fails

Comment: The request doesn't fail it just times out constantly

Comment: I tested it and it appears that Crawlera is banned by this website, since I get 503 errors from Crawlera

Comment: I tested on so many https websites and the result is the same just timeouts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179883/discussion-between-blanquer-adrien-and-mohamed-elmahdi).